# Can't retrieve variables from url

Tags: php

I can't seem to get the 'required_ids' array in my url to be passed into a php variable.  Basically I just want to count the size of the array in php so I can put that number in a DB. The problem I have is getting the url string into a variable to pull the requested_ids out.

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/somedirectory?sk=14058889342675&requested_ids%5B0%5D=51630110&requested_ids%5B1%5D=19109453492
```

Any ideas how I can quickly count the number of requested_ids?
Thanks

Comment: 'required_ids' isn't in that url. do you mean 'requested_ids'? also there should be an '=' sign after each key before it's value.

Comment: Yeah I meant 'requested_ids':)  Regarding the '=' sign they are there after the 'requested_ids%5B0%5D' which is in fact 'requested_ids[0]' because of the special character escapes. I'll post code momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this to see what is in [**`$_GET`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) *(which contains the values passed in the URL)* :

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

You'll get the following kind of output :

```
array
  'sk' => string '14058889342675' (length=14)
  'requested_ids' => 
    array
      0 => string '51630110' (length=8)
      1 => string '19109453492' (length=11)
```

Which means you can use `$_GET['requested_ids']` to know what is in that array.

And, using [**`count()`**](http://php.net/count) on that array :

```
var_dump(count($_GET['requested_ids']));
```

You will get :

```
int 2
```

Basically, when values are passed in the query-string using `[]`, like this :

```
requested_ids[0]=51630110&requested_ids[1]=19109453492
```

They end up in a PHP array, in `$_GET`, called `requested_ids`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I'll try these suggestions and post back

Comment: Yeah, just as I thought.  I had tried this before and the result I get is still int 0. The above url is the what comes out of inviting friends on a facebook app and thus I am trying to count the request_ids aka: invites. I have also tried POST and REQUEST and still no luck.

Comment: so far you have spelled the parameter name 3 different ways. Hopefully you have tried a var_dump on the entire $_GET as suggested by PMartin

Comment: Sorry for the mispelling and thanks for the help.  $_GET['requested_ids'] didn't work for me when I was trying to get requested_ids on the facebook inviter's end, which had the url format in my original example above.  But $_GET['requested_ids'] did work on the recipients end where the requested_ids are also posted.  The difference in the url format was that it had 'requested_ids=51630110' rather than the format 'requested_ids%5B0%5D=51630110'. See the difference? I'm not sure why it worked on one and not the other but it did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHP's [`count()`](https://www.php.net/count) on `$_GET['recrivied_ids']` array. Or you can [**`serialize`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)(very useful) `requested_ids` array before sending and send it via `_GET`. It should be easier than array in URL.

Example:

```
  echo 'Parameters number: ' . count($_GET['requested_ids']);
```

When serialized:

```
  $requested_ids = unserialize($_GET['requested_ids');
  echo count($requested_ids);
```

Hope it helps. ;)